# How to create temp table from a dynamic query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, dynamicquery

I want to create dynamic query for paging [**Main Motive**], here is my code:

```
Alter proc proc_GetData
(
    @TableName varchar(500)='tblPropertyType',
    @PrimaryKey varchar(500)='Id',
    @Columns varchar(max)='PropertyType',
    @WhereCondition varchar(max)='',
    @RecsPerPage int =3,
    @Page int=1,
    @SortColumn varchar(500)='Id',
    @SortDirection Varchar(56)='asc'
)
as
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
SET @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SET @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1)
select @FirstRec
select @LastRec
SET @SQL='
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SortColumn+ ' '+ @SortDirection +') RowNum,'+ @PrimaryKey +' , ' +@Columns + ' from ' +@TableName+ ' Where  1=1 '+
@WhereCondition
```

What I want to do is:

- First: inert all the records in a temp table from the above query.
- Second: `SELECT * FROM @TEMPResult WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec AND RowNum < @LastRec`.

Please help me

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
SET @SQL='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (ORDER BY ' + @SortColumn+ ' ' + @SortDirection + ') RowNum, ' + @PrimaryKey + ', ' + @Columns + ' 
   INTO tempTableName
   FROM ' + @TableName + ' Where  1 = 1 ' + @WhereCondition
```

Comment: Do you realize that `INTO tempTableName` isn't a temp table?

Comment: @bluefeet but it's *named* temp which is what matters, right? that way nobody else can use it. /sarcasm

Comment: if he would rather not drop the temporary table after use he can prepend it with # - but downgrading the answer for nit picking is a little disappointing...

Comment: Downvoting is for the benefit of the wider audience. This query cannot be run by multiple users simultaneously. Using an actual temporary table (with a name prefixed with a `#`) would fix that issue but then you would be unable to access that table outside the dynamic query's scope.

Comment: How is it nit-picking? The question clearly asks for a temporary table. Your answer should either create one or explain why this isn't needed or isn't possible or isn't advised (whatever your advice is.) An answer with just code is bareful helping.

Comment: you define a temp table as a table prefixed by a #
I define a temp table as any table that is in use temporarily, included tables prefixed by #